# C Struct where the elements cross the byte boundry and get placed in the next byte

Tags: c, struct, embedded, xilinx, cortex-a

I have the following C struct that represent a register in an external chip

```
typedef union {
    // Individual Fields
    struct {
        uint8_t ELEM_1 : 4 ; // Bits 0-3
        uint8_t ELEM_2 : 3 ; // Bits 4-6
        uint8_t ELEM_3 : 2 ; // Bits 7-8
    } field;
    // Complete Value
    uint32_t value;
} ELEMENTS_t;
```

As you can see, ELEM_1 and ELEM_2 can fit inside a byte without any issues and when accessed, the assembly code looks like this

```
    ELEMENTS.field.ELEM_2 = 0x7;
  101488:   e55b3028    ldrb    r3, [fp, #-40]  ; 0xffffffd8
  10148c:   e3833070    orr r3, r3, #112    ; 0x70
  101490:   e54b3028    strb    r3, [fp, #-40]  ; 0xffffffd8
    ELEMENTS.field.ELEM_1 = 0xf;
  101494:   e55b3028    ldrb    r3, [fp, #-40]  ; 0xffffffd8
  101498:   e383300f    orr r3, r3, #15
  10149c:   e54b3028    strb    r3, [fp, #-40]  ; 0xffffffd8
```

They all get written in the same byte with the corret bit order.

The problem is when we get to ELEM_3. That element crosses the byte boundry, since it should be placed in bits[8:7] and to avoid having multiple memory accesses (probably) the compiler places it in a completely separate byte, so when I try to access it, it looks like this

```
    ELEMENTS.field.ELEM_3  = 0x3;
  10147c:   e55b3027    ldrb    r3, [fp, #-39]  ; 0xffffffd9
  101480:   e3833003    orr r3, r3, #3
  101484:   e54b3027    strb    r3, [fp, #-39]  ; 0xffffffd9
```

This doesn't cause issues when accessing these elements field by field, but it does when trying to flush the data to the external chip.

Does anybody know how to tell the compiler to pack all the bits together? This is using the Xilinx SDK targeting the ARM Cortex-A9 processor embedded inside a Zynq SoC.

Comment: What about: `uint8_t  ELEM_1 : 4, ELEM_2 : 3, ELEM_3 : 2;`? Note that this is 9 bits, so you may need to adjust one of the numbers

Comment: Your comment about "flushing data to external chip" is worrying.  Please note that it's entirely up to the compiler to arrange bitfields in any way it chooses.  Therefore you should _not_ make any assumptions about the structure's representation in memory.  If you are sending the structure as raw bytes, you will need to either pack the bits yourself (i.e. not using bitfields), or serialize one bitfield at a time.

Comment: @paddy Bitfields are quite common for accessing hardware on some arches (e.g. `pic18f`). Usually, the variable is marked `volatile`, so the per bit actions are serialized.

Comment: In that case, the simple fix is probably to change the `uint8_t` fields to `uint16_t`.

Comment: I avoid Bitfields for registers because they are non-portable and not defined if bit 0 is MSB or LSB as it depends upon the compiler.  Also what about clearing separate fields at the same time.  It's a mess if you want to write a driver for an I2C device that can be used on both big-endian and little-endian hosts.

Comment: @Fred I agree.  While I don't do embedded programming, the same applies for systems programming, network protocols, data formats, etc.  If a bit must be in a specific position, then you damn well code it that way!

Comment: all of the separate sequences in a `union` 'should' be defined as the same length.  Also it depends on the underlying architecture as to will these bits start at the left end or the right end of the underlying 32 bit memory.  This makes such bit field declarations to be non-portable

Comment: Yep. Using bitfields to address hardware bits is an inherently bad and non-portable way of doing things. You are coding for a specific make and version of your compiler with no standard protecting you. The next version of your compiler might add pad bits, revert bit order, or revert bitfield order in the byte, it is entiteld by the standard to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pack 9 bits into a byte.  So it crosses the byte boundary.  If the register is a single byte it should only access bits 0 through 7.

There could be other problems with this if you need to set multiple bits at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If I set all the elements as uint32_t instead of uint8_t, it reads and writes the register 32-bits at a time, which makes the operations work.

```
    ELEMENTS.field.ELEM_3 = 0x3;
  10147c:   e15b32b8    ldrh    r3, [fp, #-40]  ; 0xffffffd8
  101480:   e3833d06    orr r3, r3, #384    ; 0x180
  101484:   e14b32b8    strh    r3, [fp, #-40]  ; 0xffffffd8
    ELEMENTS.field.ELEM_2 = 0x7;
  101488:   e55b3028    ldrb    r3, [fp, #-40]  ; 0xffffffd8
  10148c:   e3833070    orr r3, r3, #112    ; 0x70
  101490:   e54b3028    strb    r3, [fp, #-40]  ; 0xffffffd8
    ELEMENTS.field.ELEM_1 = 0xf;
  101494:   e55b3028    ldrb    r3, [fp, #-40]  ; 0xffffffd8
  101498:   e383300f    orr r3, r3, #15
  10149c:   e54b3028    strb    r3, [fp, #-40]  ; 0xffffffd8
```

Comment: This is right. If you wanted to save more space you could use uint16_t instead. The ELEM3 was overflowing into the next byte. If the hardware has bits which are placed like this then you have to use uint16_t or uint32_t to define the bit fields.